# Can we use present perfect in "She has packed my things when I was away"?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I was wondering if it is possible to write this

> She **has packed** my things when I **was** away

I don't think so because "when I was away" refers to the past and "has packed" refers to the present (it began in the past but ended in present), so I think it is not possible. Maybe it could possible if she ended packing my things after I was coming back, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is a time clause "when I was away", which defines a specific point/period in time, so I think the past simple would be most appropriate.

> She *packed* my things **when I was away**.

However, if you want to stress that your things are packed (and that it's presently evident), and not the fact you were not there at the moment of packing, I believe you can use the present perfect. You emphasise the result, shifting attention from how and when it's been achieved.

> She **has packed** my things *when I was away*.

Comment: I agree that the emphasis makes either version work, but I'd suggest *while I was away* for both.